# Sleep mode doesn't work

Tags: suspend, power-management

For reason I don't understand, after trying to suspend the system, it wakes up after couple seconds despite no input from me, briefly shows a text screen, blanks, shows another text screen, and then goes to lock screen.

Here are screenshots of the text screens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iaVe.jpg

This happens regardless if I use sudo pm-suspend, or using power button to suspend.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows an error with the device 0003:256c:006e.0003, which seems to be an Huion tablet. Maybe disconnecting it could help solving the problem.

Comment: Sadly, that's not it. After doing that it instead wakes up after a blank screen. But thank you for your time!

Comment: However, you were correct about it being a Huion tablet. The text is probably since it doesn't function correctly on Linux (something I don't care much about since all my art programs are on Windows anyway).